# How to reduce unnecessary thumbnail creation?

Tags: thumbnails

On a site that has many different image sizes each time an image is uploaded all the different thumbnail sizes are created causing a fair bit of bloat.
What would be the best way of optimising this process?

With a custom post type of **‘product’**, where the different product type images have slightly different aspect orientations, should (the plugin) register all the possible image sizes? e.g.

```
add_image_size('small-A', 45, 67, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('small-B', 35, 49, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('small-C', 42, 65, array('center', 'center'));
add_image_size('small-D', 50, 50, array('center', 'center'));...
```

But assuming when the plugin creates a product A, and the front end will never use the other formats for that size; should one only register the necessary sizes for ‘A’ format before running `media_handle_upload()`, would that affect the front end?

Or, run `remove_image_size()` on all the unnecessary image sizes just before `media_handle_upload()`?

Or, is there a different / best-practice approach?

Obviously, impact on performance, scalability and especially impact on storage are of some concern.

Thanks in advance.

(PS. one could conceivably just generate a standard image size and place the appropriately sized image inside that with PHP, but that seems a bit like cheating and possibly creating scaling problems down the road)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-sizes/) for this.

If you want to do it by writing your own code, you may use [`remove_image_size()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_image_size).

```
add_action('init', 'wpse325870_remove_plugin_image_sizes');
function wpse325870_remove_plugin_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size('small-A');
}
```

Note that you cannot remove [reserved image sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Reserved_Image_Size_Names) using this function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the images if you want to increase your site speed. You can optimize and compress the images by using smush images plugin => https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/

This plugin can compress and optimize all the images and increase your site speed.In this way you can also save your storage space.